# Search and replace Spanish characters in robot framework

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am reading file from unix server and importing in robot framework.Due to some spanish characters in the file i am converting the file in UFT-8 format.When file is converted in UFT-8 format spanish characters are converted into some question mark value (�).Example of one is like below

Pac�fico

Now I want to convert this special character to dot(.).How do i achieve this in robot framework?Or is there any other way I first convert on unix server and then import file in robot framework?

Comment: As most of Python and Robot Framework works in unicode, which supports these special characters, why convert to UTF-8 at all?

Comment: Yes i am able to save Pac�fico in robot framework.But this was my specific requirement to convert to dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using keyword [Replace String](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Replace%20String) from the `String` library.

```
 ${str} =   Replace String      Pac�fico    �     .
```

Comment: tried this.But getting error as below
 ${contents}= Replace String Pac�fico . count=-1
 FAIL : Keyword 'String.Replace String' missing value for argument 'replace_with'

Comment: The number of spaces does matter! There should be more than one space between all arguments.

Comment: Yes I am giving 4 spaces between all arguments  
${contents}= Replace String Pac�fico ABC count=-1

Comment: Ah, I see. You missed one argument - you don't say WHAT you want to replace.

Comment: Thanks you so much Psytho. I just noticed i was giving wrong format.I am able to achieve this now.